# How to write a 16bit data to I2c protocol

Tags: i2c

I am making a program in which I am interfacing INA226 with atmega8 using I2C. I need to write its register with value `4127h` . Following is the code I have done. when I am reading the register, I am  getting `41 FF`. That means I am able to write 41 but not 27. How can I do this.?

Also when I try to change the value like from `4127h` to `3637h` (just to check), it doesnt get change and display the older value `41 Ff`.
Please help, thanks.

CODE

```
i2c_init();
i2c_start();
i2c_write(0b10000000);  //slave address
i2c_write(0x00);        //register address
i2c_write(0x41);        // data
i2c_write(0x27);        // data
i2c_stop();

i2c_start();
i2c_write(0b10000001);
temp1 = i2c_read(1);
temp2 = i2c_read(0);
i2c_stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here 
unsigned int_16 DATA=4127
i2c_init();
i2c_start();
i2c_write(0b10000000);  //slave address
i2c_write(0x00);        //register address
i2c_write((int)DATA>>8);        // data OF MSB 
i2c_write((int)DATA & 0XFF);        // data OF LSB 
i2c_stop();
```